# How can git log --all show fewer commits than git log?

Tags: git

If you checkout https://github.com/apache/wss4j and run

```
git log --follow 0283e8c6f060999f4df8aabdab1895e1517100fe -- bindings/ws-secureconversation-binding/src/main/java/org/swssf/binding/wssc/AbstractPropertiesType.java | grep commit | wc -l
```

you get `10` as output. However if you run

```
git log --follow --all -- bindings/ws-secureconversation-binding/src/main/java/org/swssf/binding/wssc/AbstractPropertiesType.java | grep  commit | wc -l
```

you get `7` as output. This remains unchanged even if you add `0283e8c6f060999f4df8aabdab1895e1517100fe` as commit to the latter command.

How can it be that `all` leads to fewer commits?

(I'm using git version 2.7.4)

Comment: The implementation of `--follow` is very hacky and leads to weird results when encountering merges. My bet would be a merge "after" the specific commit that gets reached from `--all` that sends Git down a different graph path. There are several other possibilities, though; in particular, a rename encountered "before" reaching the specified commit will also do it.

Comment: which commits are missing?

Answer (score -1):

probably because 0283e8c6f060999f4df8aabdab1895e1517100fe is not tied to any branch so if you run --all, it won't show up and therefore it could have *less* revisions.